# Navigating between multiple panels

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel, cardlayout

Can anyone tell me how to go about coding for navigation between multiple `JPanel` classes taking the event trigger from `JButton` from the objects (panels) themselves? I have read about `CardLayout`. The panel can be swapped from the events happening in the parent panel. What I want to achieve is on click of a button embedded in the panel, it should should disappear or a desired panel should be displayed. Can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: *"Can anyone tell me.."*  Sure we can, but [what have *you* tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: You are correct -- CardLayout can do this. Now all you have to do is try to write the code and see what happens. *Then* if you get stuck, please come on back and show us your code and tell us how or why it's not working. Don't try to *find* a solution, but instead try to *write* a solution. You will learn more from the effort, trust me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing about CardLayout that prevents switching cards from actions of children within the cards.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Testing extends JFrame {

    private JPanel cardHolder;
    private CardLayout cards;
    private static final String cardA = "A";
    private static final String cardB = "B";

    private class Switcher implements ActionListener{
        String card;        
        Switcher(String card) { this.card = card; }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cards.show(cardHolder, card);
        }
    }

    private void run() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel pa = new JPanel();
        JButton ba = new JButton("Switch to B");
        ba.addActionListener(new Switcher(cardB));
        pa.add(ba);
        pa.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        JPanel pb = new JPanel();
        JButton bb = new JButton("Switch to A");
        bb.addActionListener(new Switcher(cardA));
        pb.add(bb);
        pb.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

        cardHolder = new JPanel();
        cards = new CardLayout();
        cardHolder.setLayout(cards);
        cardHolder.add(pa, cardA);
        cardHolder.add(pb, cardB);
        add(cardHolder);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new testing().run();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but 1) never `extends JFrame / JDialog / JWindow` 2) use Java Naming Conventions correctly, then class name `testing` should be `Testing`

Comment: Gene, Thank alot works like a charm. My errors were trying to use panel.setVisible(), revalidate(), and repaint() methods to hide/show the panels. Sorry, I didn't post my codes I felt it won't do much. Thanks alot. I am new to StackOverFlow, is there anywhere I can +1 a solution.

Comment: *"is there anywhere I can +1 a solution."*  Not until you have enough rep. points.  Accepting an answer (like you did) is always a good way to indicate satisfaction with an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I always keep a little class called testing in my current project as a place to do quick experiments. I use an all lower case name to allow my build script to strip it in the final build.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `never extends JFrame`.  The run() method extends `JFrame`, and I can't think of a way it would be clearer if it didn't do this.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JMenu with JMenuItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) instead of to use the [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#jbutton) for switching betweens Cards